# Icons changing screen postion

Tags: motorola-droid, app-widgets, home-screen, home-screen-shortcuts

Every so often I will unlock my phone and notice an Icon is missing on my home screen. Upon further investigation it seems that I can always find it on the home screen to the left or right. My question is: how does this happen? I have tried everything I could possibly think of to reproduce moving the icon from screen to screen. It doesn't pertain to a particular icon or icon position, it can happen with any of them. Until recently I thought this didn't affect widgets but I noticed it happen with the Google search bar... It's not that big of a deal because I can quickly delete the icon and put a new one on the proper home screen. I just want to understand how this is happening, it has been going on long enough and frequently enough to make think it is not the phone but something I am doing. I have replaced my original DROID 3 times since I got it and have seen this problem since 2.0 on my the original one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible that you're long-pressing the icon and then sliding it over to the other screen.  This is also how you could put it back where you want it without deleting and re-adding the icon/widget.  Several times I've inadvertantly rested a finger on the keyboard long enough to bring up the menu.

Comment: That's what I originally thought, but I have tried to move an icon between home screen and not found any way to do it. I can't speak for other phones but when I long press on an icon there is no way to the change screens. sliding my other finger just picks up the icon on that with that finger and holding it on the edge does nothing.

Comment: My Droid2 has given me problems with recognizing that I want it to slide the icon to the next screen. Haven't had it randomly move them though.

Comment: @Kyle: on most home apps, to move icon/widget to a different screen you long press on the icon/widget then slide it to the direction of the other home screen, wait for a few second with your finger on the edge of the screen. If after a few second the screen hasn't flipped yet, you probably are not close enough to the edge. Some hard casing that covers the edge of the screen may make this more difficult to do.

Comment: Nice! I just wasn't holding my finger on the edge long enough. That explains everything.